# Nested AJAX Functions - 500 Internal Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to run a script and then if there's success, I want to run another script. I'm doing this through jQuery and AJAX. I've tried both scripts individually and they both work by themselves (the AJAX functions). Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/v/vspfiles/inventory-update/automation.asp',
   success:function(data){
       if(data=="True"){
           $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
               data:"filename=inventory.csv",                
               url: '/v/vspfiles/inventory-update/createxml.asp',
               success:function(data){
                   alert('it worked');
               }
           });
       }
    }
});
```

I get a 500 internal error on the `/v/vspfiles/inventory-update/createxml.asp?filename=inventory.csv` when I run the code this way. I don't know why since the code works when I visit the page directly and when I run the AJAX by itself but when it's nested I get a 500 error.

Any idea why that would be happening? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code; nesting of ajax calls is allowed. Your server may be configured improperly. You can try to delay the second ajax call to see if that make any difference.

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/v/vspfiles/inventory-update/automation.asp',
   success:function(data){
       if(data=="True"){
          setTimeout( function() {
           $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
               data:"filename=inventory.csv",                
               url: '/v/vspfiles/inventory-update/createxml.asp',
               success:function(data2){
                   alert('it worked');
               }
           });
         },5000 );
       }
    }
});
```

5 seconds may be too long but it should prove to you that nesting ajax calls is quite proper and may point to what configuration changes may be required on the server. Give it a try. After all, that's what troubleshooting is all about.